# Mongo Command to filter a field based on its length

Tags: javascript, mongodb, collections, robo3t

I have a mongo collection where Iam trying to filter all the records with a specific field of length =1

Iam trying to use below command and it gave below error ,can someone help here

```
db.getCollection('accdetails').find({$where:"bankDetails.length = 1"}).sort({$natural:-1})
```

Below is the error

```
Error: error: {
"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : "ReferenceError: bankDetails is not defined :\n_funcs5@:1:24\n",
"code" : 139
}
```

But I have bankDetails field in my object

** EDIT to be more precise*
Below is my record

```
{
"id" : "123",
"bankDetails" : {
    "bankdata" : {
        "banknum" : {}

    },
    "accountdata" : {
        "accnum" : {}

    }

}
}
```

For some records accountdata is missing so I want to view the  records where it dont have accountdata object in the record.

How can i query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$where is a regular JavaScript statement so you should use double equal sign to compare values:

```
db.getCollection('accdetails').find({$where:"this.bankDetails.length == 1"}).sort({$natural:-1})
```

Also you need to reference current document by using `this`.

You can also use [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/size/) which will be faster in this case, because for $where MongoDB needs to process your JavaScript expression ([docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/index.html)) so it should be avoided whenever possible:

```
db.getCollection('accdetails').find({ bankDetails: { $size: 1 } }).sort({$natural:-1})
```

EDIT:

If you want to get `bankDetails` only where there is `accountData` missing you should use [$exists](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) operator:

```
db.getCollection('accdetails').find({ 'bankDetails.accountdata': { $exists: false } }).sort({$natural:-1})
```

Comment: Thanks.mickl it didnt worked in my case..Apologies maybe I didnt formatted the question properly.I have added my sample record and asked question indetail.can u have a look

Comment: @hammy, I've modified my answer, try with $exists operator

Comment: Thanks .It worked .one last help ,what in case I need to find records where both id exists and bankDetails.accountdata don't exists?

Comment: .find({ 'bankDetails.accountdata': { $exists: false }, 'id': { $exists: true } })